# Data Pump Export Wizard throwing errors

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, datapump

I have inherited an old Oracle Server running Oracle 10g, I have very few info about the system except a couple of logins credentials and we are busy with a third party getting the application migrated to a newer platform.

For them to analyze the current system they asked us to provided a Data Pump

I have created a Data Pump directory and use SQL Developer Data Pump Wizard

Here is the output of the command:

```
Error starting at line : 8 in command - DECLARE
    TYPE empcurtyp IS REF CURSOR;
    v_emp_cursor   empcurtyp;   --emp_record      employees%ROWTYPE;
    v_stmt_str     VARCHAR2(200);   --v_e_job         employees.job%TYPE;
    ona            VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE);
    jn             VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE);
    jm             VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE);
    s              VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE);
    fnameplsql    varchar2(4000 byte):= :FNAME; BEGIN   -- Dynamic SQL statement with placeholder:
    v_stmt_str := 'select  OWNER_NAME, JOB_NAME, JOB_MODE, STATE FROM SYS.DBA_DATAPUMP_JOBS where OWNER_NAME||''.''||job_name=:fin'
    ;

  -- Open cursor & specify bind variable in USING clause:
    BEGIN
        OPEN v_emp_cursor FOR v_stmt_str
            USING fnameplsql;

  -- Fetch rows from result set one at a time:

        LOOP
            FETCH v_emp_cursor INTO
                ona,
                jn,
                jm,
                s;
            EXIT;
        END LOOP;

  -- Close cursor:
        CLOSE v_emp_cursor;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            BEGIN
                BEGIN
                    if (v_emp_cursor%isopen) then
                        CLOSE v_emp_cursor;
                    end if;
                EXCEPTION
                    WHEN OTHERS THEN
                        NULL;
                END;
    -- Dynamic SQL statement with placeholder:
                v_stmt_str := 'select  user OWNER_NAME, JOB_NAME, JOB_MODE, STATE FROM user_DATAPUMP_JOBS where user||''.''||job_name=:fin'
                ;

  -- Open cursor & specify bind variable in USING clause:
                BEGIN
                    OPEN v_emp_cursor FOR v_stmt_str
                        USING fnameplsql;   -- Fetch rows from result set one at a time:

                    LOOP
                        FETCH v_emp_cursor INTO
                            ona,
                            jn,
                            jm,
                            s;
                        EXIT;
                    END LOOP;

  -- Close cursor:
                    CLOSE v_emp_cursor;
                EXCEPTION
                    WHEN OTHERS THEN
                        BEGIN
                            BEGIN
                                if (v_emp_cursor%isopen) then
                                     CLOSE v_emp_cursor;
                                end if;
                            EXCEPTION
                                WHEN OTHERS THEN
                                    NULL;
                            END;
                        END;
                END;

            END;
    END;
    --owner_name and job_name could be any valid value - could have been double quoted on the way in
    :OWNER_NAME:=ona;
    :JOB_NAME:=jn;
    :OWNER_NAMEQ:=SYS.DBMS_ASSERT.simple_sql_name(SYS.DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(ona,false));
    :JOB_NAMEQ:=SYS.DBMS_ASSERT.simple_sql_name(SYS.DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(jn,false));
    :STATE:=s;
    /* dbms_output.put_line(ona
                         || ':'
                         || jn
                         || ':'
                         || trim(jm)
                         || ':'
                         || s);*/

END;
```

And the errors:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 86, column 22:
PLS-00201: identifier 'SYS.DBMS_ASSERT' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 86, column 6:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 87, column 22:
PLS-00201: identifier 'SYS.DBMS_ASSERT' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 87, column 6:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

CHECKING MASTER TABLE


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.




Error starting at line : 131 in command -
BEGIN
  IF (:UTL_ERROR IS NOT NULL) THEN
    Raise_application_error(-20001,:UTL_ERROR);
  END IF;
END;
Error report -
ORA-20001: STATE IS NULL
ORA-06512: at line 3
```

Comment: Connect as SYS and `grant execute on dbms_assert to user_that_runs_this_procedure` and see what happens.

Comment: I am actually logged in as system SQL> grant execute on dbms_assert to system;
grant execute on dbms_assert to system
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04042: procedure, function, package, or package body does not exist

Comment: SYS, as well as SYSTEM, own the database. They *should* see everything. This is 10g (which is version you use) documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/pls/db102/homepage . Search for "dbms_assert" returns nothing; it seems that it was introduced in a later version (11g has it). Are you sure that this code ran on 10g?

Comment: @Littlefoot i had same question, not sure dbms_assert is in 10g...i thought it had been added for 10gR2 though..in either scenario, sqldev doesn't support 10g, so they may want to look at the CLI for data pump